# Design Patterns: How would you describe the MVC model?

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns

Ok, I need to give some attributes to describe what MVC model means for a developer. And the only word that hits for the moment it's modularization (separation).

And the funny thing is that I need to give some adjectives, not nouns. :| Any help? :)

Comment: Are you asking about the M (model) part of MVC or the whole design pattern?

Answer (score 5):

To be honest, modular is going to be about as much as you'll come up with, simply because that's the basic idea behind it.

You could probably call on the old favourites, `loosely coupled` and `highly coherent`, meaning that the three parts have a very small interface between them but each part in itself is fully self-contained. Or, although it's not as pithy (nor technically an adjective), `conforming to a distinct separation of duties`.

In other words, the model is *all* the data-based stuff with no presentation or control information, similarly the controller part knows nothing about the data or how it's viewed, instead containing only control flow.

Beyond that, I can't provide much more help without referring to a thesaurus.